# Entity Framework Core - How to correctly define primary key that is also a foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
class Topic {
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
}

public class Post {
   public int PostId { get; set; }
   public int TopicId { get; set; } 
}
```

Topic.TopicId and Post.PostId are based on a SQL Sequence called "PostIdSequence". If the TopicId and PostId are the same, it means this particular post is the "topic post".

I want to be able to do something like this when creating a new "Topic" (this should have a matching Post with same PostId and TopicId):

```
var topic = new Topic() {};
var post = new Post() {};
DbContext.Topics.Add(topic);
DbContext.Posts.Add(post);
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

So basically, it should automatically populate "Topic.TopicId" with the next value of the PostIdSequence and then also assign it to Post.PostId.

What is the "correct" way of creating these entity classes?

Comment: You need to inform EF that `Post` is related to `Topic` through a property on the object that you assign, not just the `TopicId`.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong.. 
As per my understanding I think you are violating the SQL basic...

You can not make PK as a FK and also can not make more then 1 PK in same table.

> To fix your problem you must declared max 1 PK and 1 or more than 1
>   FK.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Standard
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public Standard Standard { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any query.